# Jframe does not remember it' s position after minimizing

Tags: java, jframe

My problem is that ,
The Jframe window does not remember it's position after minimizing ....suppose I minimize at co'ordiates (45,89)..but after maximizing it again open at (37,28)..means at different co-ordinates ..i want that jframe should open at the same position...after maximizing..like remeber it's position..

please help

Comment: I have never seen this problem before. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem as well as the JDK version and platform you are using so people can verify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could save its position before being minimized and then, when it is restored, reset is location.

```
public class A extends JFrame implements WindowListener{
  //...

  private Point p;
  public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    //minimized
    p = getLocation();
  }
  public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    //restored
    setLocation(p);
  }
}
```